# Font-face not working in IE9

Tags: font-face

I am facing font-face issue 
I am using gotham font check below code:

```
@font-face{  
font-family: Gotham MEDIUMITA;
src: url('Gotham_Font/GOTHAM-MEDIUMITA.OTF')format("truetype");  
}
```

Its working in IE8,firefox,chrome. But in IE9 font is not applying...
is there any solution pls help regarding this....

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using this font in a web page violates your font license from H&FJ. Secondly, there are a couple of reasons that it might not be working:

1. IE9 requires that any raw TTF linked with @font-face have the OS/2 fsType code embedded in the font be set to 'Installable'. Likely your font does not have this set correctly. You can fix this by using a WOFF or EOT instead. See the correct syntax for a font-face declaration here: http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax/
2. Your font-family name should ideally be "in_quotes_with_no_spaces"

Comment: Thanks for reply   Actually I have only one type file like above mentioned OTF file is it required TTF file or any other file?

Comment: You might try changing the format hint to: format("opentype");